# Best way to represent a wide grid for printing?

Tags: layout, printing, grid

We have many WIDE html grids which scroll horizontally within a DIV in our web application.

I would like to find the best strategy for printing these grids on a portrait A4 page.

What I would like to know is what is the best way to present/display grids/data like this.

This question is not HTML specific, I am looking for design strategies and not CSS @page directives.

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a whole book dedicated (amongst other things) to fast methods for the computation of \pi: 'Pi and the AGM', by Jonathan and Peter Borwein (available on Amazon).

I studied the AGM and related algorithms quite a bit: it's quite interesting (though sometimes non-trivial).

Note that to implement most modern algorithms to compute \pi, you will need a multiprecision arithmetic library (GMP is quite a good choice, though it's been a while since I last used it).

The time-complexity of the best algorithms is in O(M(n)log(n)), where M(n) is the time-complexity for the multiplication of two n-bit integers (M(n)=O(n log(n) log(log(n))) using FFT-based algorithms, which are usually needed when computing digits of \pi, and such an algorithm is implemented in GMP).

Note that even though the mathematics behind the algorithms might not be trivial, the algorithms themselves are usually a few lines of pseudo-code, and their implementation is usually very straightforward (if you chose not to write your own multiprecision arithmetic :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it really depends on what your purpose is.

- **In a book format**: I usually try span two facing pages.
- **For a conference or poster**: Find an extra wide printer and print it out on a large sheet of paper.
- **Something more informal**: Span regular pages and tape them together.
- **Powerpoint**: Don't show the whole chart, they'll not be able to read the details anyways, just show the relevant information.